# Find the principal part of $\tan z + \tan(z-a)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How can I find the principal part of $\tan z + \tan(z-a)$ ? Do I have to find the Laurent Expansion of each function, then do the sum and after that find the principal part? Finding the Laurent Expansion of $\tan z$ is quite difficult. I am assuming that $a$ is not a multiple integer of $\pi$

Thank you.